# IPython Modify Plot with Container Widget

Tags: widget, ipython, jupyter

I'm working with the Ipython widgets to modify dynamically plotted data, so i get the result as seen in the image; however i dont like the arrangment of the widgets (sliders and float boxes) so i have tried to align them horizontally with `Box` and here is the trouble because i don't know how to pass this arrangment to the function, this is how i obtain what you see in the image

```
#I'm just going to put two sliders
x= FloatSlider(0,1000)
y= FloatSlider(0,1000)

interactive(Function,Xo=x,Yo=y)
```

if i try

```
x= FloatSlider(0,1000,10)
y= FloatSlider(-1,1,0.1)

#this gives me the desired arrangment
co = HBox(children=[x,y])

interactive(Function,Xo=Co.children[0],Yo=Co.children[1])
```

this just gives me the same unordered result, and here is where i got stuck, i don't know how to input the container to make it work with my plot. Where is my error? what can i do?

[image]

Comment: You can't currently use interact/interactive with container widgets, as far as I know. If you want to specify your own layout, you have to hook up the `on_trait_change` handlers of each widget to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be a solution for your problem:

```
from IPython.html.widgets import *
x = FloatSlider(value = 500.0, min=0.0, max=1000.0, step=10)
y = FloatSlider(value = 0.0, min=-1.0, max=1.0, step=0.1)
plt.xlim(0,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)

def Function(x, y):
    plt.plot([0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0], 'b.')
    plt.plot(x/1000.0, y, 'o')

#this gives me the desired arrangment
f = interactive(Function, x=x, y=y)
Co = HBox(f.children)

display(Co)
```